# How to handle unicode issues in PHP?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

how do i properly handle unicode issues in PHP. Do i just set UTF-8 as a parameter to any function that needs it or do i set it as the locale somewhere in the bootstrap file once? How do it affect mysql etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to set a global encoding in PHP. The best you can do is, always use the `mb_` family of functions, and try to always be explicit about the encoding you want to use.

As for mysql, in particular, you can make sure that it connects using utf-8, usually by calling a set encoding method/function right after connecting or in the constructor if you're using pdo (see http://ar.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php.)

Using utf-8 with PHP requires some discipline, but, it's definitly worth it. Hope any of this helps.